# Accessing global variables in parallel process using parallel.js in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, parallel-processing

I'm trying to access data from the main thread using paralleljs. This is my code:

```
var Parallel = require('paralleljs');
var b = 2
var p = new Parallel(3, {
    env: {
        b: b,
    }
});
p.spawn(function(){
    console.log(global.env.b);
}).then(function(){
});
```

Apparently global.env is undefined.